# can't upload image from URL

Tags: java, android

I create Android App and want upload image from URL to ImageView.
In Android manifest set permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Try upload image from URL

```
public void getBitmapfromURL( String src )
{
  try
  {
    URL url = new URL( src );
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = url.openStream();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    return bmp;
  }
  catch( Exception ex )
  {
    Log.i("MyMessage", "ERROR!!!!");

    return null;
  }
}
```

My stack trace when I try upload image from URL

```html
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.example.testloadimg.MainActivity.getBitmapfromURL(MainActivity.java:35)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.example.testloadimg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 22:36:33.501: E/MyMessage(4605): ERROR!!!!
12-28 22:36:33.685: D/libEGL(4605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-28 22:36:33.693: D/(4605): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7dd9ab0, tid 4605
12-28 22:36:33.717: D/libEGL(4605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-28 22:36:33.717: D/libEGL(4605): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-28 22:36:33.901: W/EGL_genymotion(4605): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-28 22:36:33.909: E/OpenGLRenderer(4605): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
12-28 22:36:33.913: E/OpenGLRenderer(4605): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
12-28 22:36:33.937: E/OpenGLRenderer(4605): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
12-28 22:36:33.941: E/OpenGLRenderer(4605): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
12-28 22:36:33.941: D/OpenGLRenderer(4605): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: ERROR. It can't set connect with URL

Comment: Change Log.i("MyMessage", "ERROR!!!!"); to Log.e("ERROR", "", ex); Provide url please.

Comment: http://zagroup.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo-img-cz.png

Comment: Please do what I said first, and add stack trace in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but where "stack trace" in Eclipse?

Comment: Exactly in the same place where you saw "ERROR!!!!!" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very clear with this line:

```
12-28 22:36:33.501: W/System.err(4605): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

which means you should move your network connection related code, and put them into a separate thread.

Please take a look at the `AsyncTask` section in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Network code on the UI thread in Strict mode since 3.0, you can either override this which is a bad practice:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

or create an AsyncTask -as an inner class for example- that would load the image:

```
private Bitmap myBitmapFromURL;
private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private ImageView imageView;    

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String src = params[0];
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    myBitmapFromURL = result;
}
}
```

And then to run the task:

```
new ImageLoadTask().execute("URL of the file");
```

Comment: Thanks! I myself created AsyncTask. I practice and now I know how to do it:-)